# Are questions about "game cheating" for example legit?

Tags: discussion

I just came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783152/how-to-destruct-a-jar-to-appear-that-it-never-existed) where the questioner is basically asking how to improve his cheat application so that it can't be detected later on; probably when some admin detects wrongdoing and inspects a system.

Although not exactly a great question content wise; I am not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Its a programming question and thus on topic.  The fact its a bad question is an entirely separate matter.  The reason it received negative votes is because of the quality of the question itself not because its about writing a cheat for a game.

Comment: Well, that is speculation. Nobody can say what each downvoter was thinking when making that click.